# Extending Date.prototype in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Please help me understand why this works for Number but not for Date.

```
declare interface Number {
    toPreferredStringFormat(): string;
}

declare interface Date {
    toPreferredStringFormat: string;
}

(function () {
    // OK
    Number.prototype.toPreferredStringFormat = () => {
        return this.toString() + " preferred!";
    };

    // ERROR (why?!)
    Date.prototype.toPreferredStringFormat = () => {
        return this.toString() + " preferred!";
    };
})();
```

Am I doing it right?

Thanks!

Comment: Your declaration is different. I don't know Typescript, but it looks like you declare `Date.toPreferredStringFormat` to be a string not a function

Comment: Ah, can't believe it! Thanks for your eye! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between your two declarations...

```
toPreferredStringFormat(): string; // has ()
toPreferredStringFormat: string; // doesn't have ()
```

The second of these two says the property is a string, the first says it is a function.

Here is a full working example, using the long-hand way of saying that you expect a function returning a string, this makes it more obvious than just the presence of brackets, but that works too:

```
declare interface Number {
    toPreferredStringFormat: () => string;
}

declare interface Date {
    toPreferredStringFormat: () => string;
}

(function () {
    // OK
    Number.prototype.toPreferredStringFormat = () => {
        return this.toString() + " preferred!";
    };

    // ERROR (why?!)
    Date.prototype.toPreferredStringFormat = () => {
        return this.toString() + " preferred!";
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me, when I wanted to extend Date prototype with a new method is this:

```
declare global {
    interface Date{
        yyyymmdd: () => string;    
    }
}
```

I picked this up from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7726#issuecomment-204056766)